# How to inspect CalibratedClassifierCV BaseEstimator parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, random-forest

I got a task to inspect and compare two already trained ML model developed by somebody else. The difference in the models is different input datasets. The first one is trained on 2018 data and second one on 2019 data. It is a `RandomForestClassifier` model at it's core, trained in `sklearn.pipeline` module. The problem is, that there is a `CalibratedClassifierCV` in the middle that complifies my access to the random forest model itself. So I have no deep knowledge about the model and it looks like a black box to me. The pipeline in both cases is identical.

**Edit:** Added a reproducible steps into how the pipeline was created, but without the dataset:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV, calibration_curve
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

RF_clf = RandomForestClassifier()
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaling', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
                        ('classifier', CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=RF_clf, cv=2, method='sigmoid'))])

# Further steps not replicated from code because of additional custom made training and fitting functions but these are the steps:

# fit model on train data
# predict model on test data
```

What I wanted to do or see as a next step, from the already trained model that I read from disk as a `model.pkl` file, is a `.feature_importance_` of the models, because random forest natively supports it. Then I would compare the distribution of the most important features between the years. But it is not accessible.

Here is how far I could get with the model inspection:

These worked:

```py
pipeline.named_steps
pipeline.named_steps['classifier']

CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=0, verbose=1, warm_start=False),
            cv=2, method='sigmoid')
```

But I cannot go deeper.

This one already doesn't work:

```py
pipeline.named_steps['classifier']['base_estimator']

TypeError: 'CalibratedClassifierCV' object is not subscriptable
```

I also tried `eli5` library to see some info, but it seems the `CalibratedClassifierCV` is not supported:

```py
eli5.explain_weights(pipeline_rf.named_steps['classifier'])

Error: estimator CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=0, verbose=1, warm_start=False), cv=2, method='sigmoid') is not supported
```

Do you have some experience on how to go deeper into `CalibratedClassifierCV` and really look at the feature importance of the `BaseEstimator` model? Thank you for any tips.

Comment: how abt `pipeline.named_steps['classifier'].base_estimator`?

Comment: Please think about [reprex]. As a side note, `BaseEstimator` is a parent class from which all estimators inherit. Probably not what you want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short example for accessing the underlying `RandomForestClassifier`'s `feature_importances_`.

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import set_config
set_config(print_changed_only=True)

X, y = make_classification()
rf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X, y)

pipe = Pipeline([('classifier',
                  CalibratedClassifierCV(rf))]).fit(X, y)
pipe['classifier'].base_estimator.feature_importances_
```

If you are looking for the comparison of the output of `CalibratedClassifierCV`s  then you need to look at the `calibrated_classifiers_` attribute.

## Update:

for sigmoid method (which is the default one), there are two parameter (a, b) learned during the fit. We can extract those two information via the following snippet.

```
for calibrated_classifier in pipe['classifier'].calibrated_classifiers_ :
    calibrator = calibrated_classifier.calibrators_[0]
    print(calibrator.a_)
    print(calibrator.b_)
```

Comment: Hi Venkatachalam, thanks for the answer, I could get into the result this way! Too bad I couldn't find example of the subscription you are providing, eg. `base_estimator.feature_importances_` instead of `['base_estimator'].feature_importances_`. Could you please give me also example on how to compare the `CalibratedClassifierCV`?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't understand when you `couldn't find example of the subscription`, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean, that I couldn't find the example somewhere online, on how to call the function parameter correctly. That's why I tried incorrectly `['base_estimator'].feature_importances_` instead of correctly `base_estimator.feature_importances_`. So it's great you could help me and this little help solves my issue already.